# jRecorder - jQuery

Tags: html

I want to record the voice using html5 and I have tried jRecorder-jQuery too. From the document, it mentioned that the binary file is saved in browser cache. My question is where it?  I have checked Chrome's cache but cannot see the temp file.

Answer (score 2):

> **host (Mandatory):** The PHP file http location where the recorded WAV file is posted.

That is from the jRecorder documentation(http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/index.html), **it seems that the file is not saved locally** and is sent trough a post request to the mentioned php page on the host settings.

### Add this in the jRecorder settings:

```
'host': 'acceptfile.php?filename=hello.wav'
```

And change the `acceptfile.php` to your php script that will handle the posted file.

### Example php script for handeling the wav file(also from the documentation):

```
   $upload_path = dirname(__FILE__). '/';

   //here assume that filename parameter is passed. or your can write $filename= 'test.wav';
   $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];

   $fp = fopen($upload_path."/".$filename.".wav", "wb");

   fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));

   fclose($fp);

   exit('done');
```

This script will save the audio file(wav) in the script folder.

Comment: HI, thanks.  Yes php part is clear.  I just wonder can I save in my local pc too and where is the temporary file store.  It must save somewhere otherwises how to produce "hello.wav"

Comment: it works on flash, so what i think is that flash stores it inside the flash object therefor you cannot save it to your local pc. it produces it by sending the "code" of the wav file to the php